# Download file from Google Drive via rest api using gzip compression

Tags: android, google-drive-api, gzip

I'm using the following code to download a publicly shared file from Google drive. It works fine.

```
InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;

HttpURLConnection httpsURLConnectionToGoogleDrive = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(downloadUrl).openConnection();
httpsURLConnectionToGoogleDrive.connect();

long fileLength = httpsURLConnectionToGoogleDrive.getContentLength();
input = httpsURLConnectionToGoogleDrive.getInputStream();

byte data[] = new byte[MediaHttpUploader.MINIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE];
int count;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    // allow canceling with back button
    if (isCancelled()) {
        input.close();
        return null;
    }
    total += count;
    log("Received Up To : "+ total + " ("+ count +") ");
    // publishing the progress....
    if (fileLength > 0) { // only if total length is known
        publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
    }
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

Now, I want to add gzip compression to save bandwidth. From [this reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/performance) I added the following code :-

```
httpsURLConnectionToGoogleDrive.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
httpsURLConnectionToGoogleDrive.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "my program (gzip)");
```

But I could't get it to work. I'm stuck here. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

The Drive API already manages the requests as gzip as default, so there is no extra effort from your side. Only if you were to create you're own library, then you should specify the headers for gzip.

Comment: I'm using the Drive rest API. So need to handle this ourselves, I guess