# How does Worker.setForegroundAsync work behind the scene?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Currently, after quit the app, to complete a long running task in foreground (So that it will not be killed by OS), this is what I did by using `WorkManager`.

1. Use `Worker` to call `ContextCompat.startForegroundService`, for starting an `IntentService`.
2. `Worker` will then return `Result.success()` immediately.
3. In `onHandleIntent` on `IntentService`, it will execute `startForeground`, before performing long running task.

Here's the code snippet.

```
public class SyncWorker extends Worker {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(WeNoteApplication.instance(), SyncForegroundIntentService.class);

        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(
                WeNoteApplication.instance(),
                intent
        );

        return Result.success();
    }
}

public class SyncForegroundIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "com.yocto.wenote.sync.SyncIntentService";

    public SyncForegroundIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        final Context context = WeNoteApplication.instance();

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(...

        startForeground(SYNC_FOREGROUND_INTENT_SERVICE_ID, builder.build());

        // Perform networking operation within foreground service.

        stopForeground(true);
```

---

I have strong intention to migrate the code, to make use of [`setForegroundAsync`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#setForegroundAsync(androidx.work.ForegroundInfo)) in `WorkManager`. The reason is that, under certain rare circumstance, I will get the following crash

> Context.startForegroundService() did not then call
>   Service.startForeground()

So, I thought migrating to `setForegroundAsync` might help eliminating this problem.

---

However, it isn't clear how `setForegroundAsync` work behind the scene, by looking at [WorkForegroundUpdater souce code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/utils/WorkForegroundUpdater.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F).

Here's the code snippet of `setForegroundAsync` code example from https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running

```
public class DownloadWorker extends Worker {
    public DownloadWorker(
        @NonNull Context context,
        @NonNull WorkerParameters parameters) {
            ...
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        ...

        // What happens behind the scene?!
        setForegroundAsync(createForegroundInfo(progress));

        // The long running task is still executed in Worker thread.
        download(inputUrl, outputFile);

        return Result.success();
    }
```

---

However, it isn't clear whether such migration will achieve equivalent outcome. As, here are their differences.

### Before migration to setForegroundAsync

1. The long running task is executed by `IntentService`'s user thread.
2. Before long running task is completed, Worker will return immediately.

### After migration to setForegroundAsync

1. The long running task is executed by `Worker`'s user thread.
2. Worker will only return after long running task is finished executing.

---

Currently, with my current implementation, I will able to avoid [Excessive network usage (background)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985675/still-getting-excessive-network-usage-background-warning-after-running-netwo) issue. I am not sure whether with `setForegroundAsync`, will I still able to avoid [Excessive network usage (background)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985675/still-getting-excessive-network-usage-background-warning-after-running-netwo) issue?

In short, does anyone has idea how Worker.setForegroundAsync work behind the scene?

Answer (score 3):

Behind the scene `setForegroundAsync()` starts a foreground service for you when you're on API >= 26, or on a normal service when running on older Android releases. This is documented in the [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#setForegroundAsync(androidx.work.ForegroundInfo)):

> *Under the hood, WorkManager manages and runs a foreground service on your behalf to execute this WorkRequest, showing the notification provided in ForegroundInfo.*

I think that the relevant source is in [`Processor.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/Processor.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F#147).

Talking about vital's metric [**Excessive Mobile Network Usage in Background**](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/bg-network-usage), I don't see how this would change in this case given that, also using WorkManager `setForegroundAsync()` will move your worker to a ForegroundService on Android Oreo+.
For additional information on how this vital's metric is measured, please, take a look at [Play Console's guide](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7385505?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! What confusing me is that, long running `download` function, is *still* being executed within `DownloadWorker`'s `doWork` function. How does it related to the newly launched foreground service? I expect `download` will be executed by newly launched foreground service. (Something like IntentService's onHandleIntent executing a time consuming function)